# Unable to add filesystem permission denied

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, google-cloud-functions

Using node v 8.9.0 and this [tutorial](https://rominirani.com/google-cloud-functions-tutorial-debugging-local-functions-357c24829198)

When I try and debug my http google cloud function in dev tools:

C:_Users_Matt_AppData_Roaming_nvm_v8.9.0_node_modules_@google-cloud_functions-emulator_src_supervis

I get filesystem permission denied error, how can I debug my cloud functions:

Answer (score 47):

I also got the filesystem permission denied error, and the issue was that you need to accept the premissions from chrome to be able to access that filesystem.  initially I didn't see the premissions prompt, but then I found it on a different tab (which was kinda weird behavior).  I guess just look for that permissions prompt, it should be right below your address bar.

[image]

Comment: The acceptance is usually found at:  ```chrome://inspect/#devices```

Comment: I have not found this agreement even here (There are no other options, is it possible to register it by hand?

Comment: To add to this, I found it the next new tab. So when I saw the error I created a new tab and there it was at the top. I had moved to other tabs first, but that didn't show the prompt.

Answer (score -2):

I see that you are referring to a C directory, which means that you are trying this on Windows OS. I will put the steps below with documentation links on how to properly setup the configuration. Those steps worked for me well without giving me any issues, so I suggest you to follow them one by one and see if that helps you.

**Run Google Cloud Functions Emulator on Windows OS:**

1. Install and set up Google Cloud SDK for Windows. [Link and documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/)
2. Install Node.js and npm for Windows. [Tutorial here](https://www.guru99.com/download-install-node-js.html)
3. Right click on Google Cloud SDK Shell and select Run as administrator.
4. Execute `$ node --version` you should get the version of Node.js without any additional errors
5. Execute `$ npm --version` you should get the version of npm without any additional errors
6. The tutorial that you are referring to is part of [Google Cloud Functions Tutorial Series](https://rominirani.com/google-cloud-functions-tutorial-series-f04b2db739cd)
7. First install and set up npm functions emulator by running `$ npm install -g @google-cloud/functions-emulator` as mentioned in [Google Cloud Functions Tutorial : Setting up a Local Development Environment](https://rominirani.com/google-cloud-functions-tutorial-setting-up-a-local-development-environment-8acd394a8b76)
8. Setup the project for the functions `$ functions config set projectId PROJECT_ID` as mentioned in [Start and Stop the Emulator](https://rominirani.com/google-cloud-functions-tutorial-using-the-local-functions-emulator-bd351bbe61de) documentation.
9. Start the emulator by executing `$ functions start`. Same documentation as above.
10. Download the source code as mentioned in the documentation you are referring to. The [GitHub repository is here](https://github.com/rominirani/googlecloudfunctions-training).
11. Clone the project locally. `$ git clone https://github.com/rominirani/googlecloudfunctions-training.git`
12. Navigate to the folder `$ cd googlecloudfunctions-training/helloworld-http`
13. Follow the rest of the [Google Cloud Functions Tutorial : Debugging Local Functions](https://rominirani.com/google-cloud-functions-tutorial-debugging-local-functions-357c24829198) documentation.

> NOTE: Whenever you run / execute / call the Cloud Function the Node.js
>   blank window will pop up. Keep it open as it is the executable that
>   executes your code.

I have tested the tutorial with the above set up that I described and it worked for me. You have to be the administrator of your account, since the Functions Emulator and the code is running locally, so you have to have all the permissions of the directories that are going to be used and execute all the software as administrator.